# Disjunctions not supported

Tags: soql, custom-metadata

Custom Metadata supports a limited SOQL syntax, and `OR` statements are not supported. From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_limitations.htm&language=en_US&type=0):

What is an alternative to the below SOQL if Salesforce does not support `OR` in this case?

```
SELECT Call_Center_Display_Script__c
FROM VDN_Mapping__mdt 
WHERE obj_name__c =: objNamePassed 
OR (obj_name__c = '' and isactive = true )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can perform an unlimited number of queries against `__mdt` ([relevant documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_limits.htm&type=0)), I'd suggest simply breaking this up into two queries.

```
Map<Id, VDN_Mapping__mdt> first_query = new Map<Id, VDN_Mapping__mdt>([SELECT Call_Center_Display_Script__c
FROM VDN_Mapping__mdt 
WHERE obj_name__c =: objNamePassed]);

Map<Id, VDN_Mapping__mdt> second_query = new Map<Id, VDN_Mapping__mdt>([SELECT Call_Center_Display_Script__c
FROM VDN_Mapping__mdt 
WHERE obj_name__c = '' and isactive = true]);
```

Combining the results (to achieve the same effect as using a single query with `OR`) is as simple as adding all the results from one map to the other

```
first_query.putAll(second_query);
```

Using a map ensures that you don't end up with duplicate results (a `Set` could also be used).