# Disjunctions not supported on a flow (Bulk?)

Tags: visual-workflow, bulk, custom-metadata

Has anyone encountered a "Disjunctions not supported" while automating with a flow getting values from a custom metadata? Do you have any recommendations?

From the reading that I did, "Disjunctions not supported" is thrown when an OR condition is used on the SOQL looking up the metadata. [1,2]

In my case, the flow does not have an OR condition on the GET (the SOQL equivalent so to speak). However, I see a pattern that looks like a bulk trigger of the flow throws this error.

Do we know whether a bulk update on the flow generate an OR condition when looking for the metadata in a flow? Is there a workaround that anyone knows about?

Thank you for any help.

Ref:

1. [Disjunctions not supported](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169815/disjunctions-not-supported)
2. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_limitations.htm&type=0 (SOQL section)

Comment: Flow does an OR if the same criteria are used in two places in get records, see [this page](https://sforce.co/2qnyh3c) where it says "When you define multiple filters, the filter logic usually defaults to AND. However, if multiple filters have the same field selected and use the equals operator, the filters are combined with OR."

Comment: Hi @gorav
Thank you for the response. Yes, I did see that. In this particular case the filter conditions are all unique. From my research it seems as if when the flow is triggered on bulk records, the GET is bulkified. I am wondering whether that would cause an OR condition. Which would be a Salesforce bug then (?)

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has indicated this is a known issue with no resolution date.
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001RXPC

The workaround for my situation was to use apex

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered similar issue so replaced my Custom metadata with custom object not ideal.  But the reported issue has few affected users so not likely to be fixed anytime soon.

Comment: This does not answer the question, you will be able to comment on posts when you will have sufficient reputation.

Comment: @debra anderson - that is an option. Though I would love the ease of deploying the metadata values and also the implied query limits on using custom metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I created a generic lookup service to get around this. Code is [here](https://github.com/BobHatcher/FlowLookup) and how-to is [here](https://www.stupidcrmtricks.com/2020/06/custom-lookup-for-flows-to-avoid.html).